# Update dentro de un Select en Mysql, o algo similar

Tags: mysql, select, update

realizo esta consulta porque la verdad no encuentro por ningún lado una respuesta ni tutorial, o no lo estoy buscando de forma correcta.
El asunto que es necesito realizar un `UPDATE` cambiando un valor de un campo de forma matemática y que a su vez me devuelva el valor resultante pero no consigo hacerlo.

Algo así:

`SELECT CAMPO_NUMERO FROM (UPDATE TABLA SET CAMPO_NUMERO=CAMPO_NUMERO+1)`

Necesito ese valor resultante, y ya que son demasiadas operaciones de este tipo, realizar un `SELECT` después de un `UPDATE` no me devuelve el valor real del campo, sino el cambiado por otra computadora que también esta operando sobre el mismo campo. Es necesario hacer el `UPDATE` y que devuelva como resultado la operación, intento esto y así evitarme hacer un procedimiento almacenado.

**Disculpen. Mysql 5.6.24 base de datos InnoDB**

Comment: Alan, falta informacion en la pregunta que es importante para quienes decidan responderla. 1) En que versión de MySql está realizando la operacion. 2) Que tipo de tablas son (InnoDB, MyISAM) ya que el escenario en el que desea la solución involucra concurrencia y posiblemente requiera bloqueo de fila para update . Posiblemente te sirva lo siguente https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html y de acuerdo al dominio del problema determinar el tipo de bloqueo que se ajuste

Comment: Para esto existen las transacciones. Actualizas el valor, luego haces el select, si está dentro de una transacción el número leido es el de la transacción, la fila se bloquea, y las demas conexiones deben esperar a que finalice tu transacción para intentar obtener nuevo número.

Answer (score 0):

Lo tenías casi.

```
UPDATE TABLA SET CAMPO_NUMERO=CAMPO_NUMERO+1 WHERE ....
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta llegara a funcionar, estaría mucho mejor que le explicaras a OP el porqué debería realizarlo de esa forma aunque parezca muy obvio, es bueno aclarárselo por si algún usuario es muy novato y no comprende el porqué debe usar el código de esa manera. Saludos ;)

Comment: Totalmente equivocado a lo que pregunte, por favor lea el enunciado completamente

Comment: Si quieres hacer un update y un select seguido sin que el cambio se vea hasta acabar el proceso para eso existen las transacciones. de lo cual ya te han respondido en los comentarios